# How to have java run terminal commands on Mac? (Echo command)

Tags: java, macos, terminal, processbuilder

How do you have java run commands on Mac? I see some examples of complex commands that is hard to follow. If I wanted to run a simple echo command from java, how would I do that? Not using osascript yet. Just want to see how you would send an echo from java to terminal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder x = new ProcessBuilder("echo"," hi");
    x.start();
}
```

This is the code I tried, but it does not work.
I think this question can help people who are trying to learn the basics of ProcessBuilder.

Comment: When I entered **[java] processbuilder** in the search field (at the top of this page) I got 8,461 results. I bet that at least one of them answers your question.

Comment: @Abra I looked at some of them and they are advanced commands. They are hard to understand. I think learning a simple command like echo would be very beneficial to people trying to learn ProcessBuilder like me.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows so the below code uses Windows `echo`. I hope you know the Mac echo command so that you can replace my command with yours.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

public class PrcBldT2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This command is for Windows operating system.
        // For MacOS, try: new ProcessBuilder("echo", "hi")
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", "hi");

        pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            int result = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exit status = " + result);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that each word in the command is a separate string. The `echo` command output will be redirected to `System.out`.

Comment: This code doesn't work on the a Mac. What is cmd.exe and /c? Also is there a difference of using spaces and having on big string that is the command or do you have to do a list of Strings?

Comment: @Benjamin Try `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "hi");`

Comment: That prints hi to the console. Two questions. Why did my example above not work? How do I get it to return to the terminal? So if I say echo hi in the java program the terminal returns hi